# Transposing the data and loading into Oracle using shell script

Tags: oracle, shell

I am trying to load the data into Oracle table from csv file using shell script. I want to transpose the data and load it to my oracle table.

CSV file data format: Below is the incoming data that i am getting.

```
Date    ,Emp_name,Math_zero,Math_max,Math_min,Math_avg,English_zero,English_max,English_min,English_avg
20161005,abc     ,0        ,1       ,0       ,0       ,0           ,1          ,0          ,0
20161005,def     ,0        ,1       ,0       ,0       ,0           ,1          ,0          ,0
```

Desired format of data while loading it to Oracle table:

```
Date    ,emp_name,subject,subject_zero,subject_max,subject_min,subject_avg
20161005,abc     ,Math   ,0           ,1          ,0          ,0
20161005,def     ,English,0           ,1          ,0          ,0
```

My Oracle table has seven columns:

`Date
Emp_name
Subject
Subject_zero
Subject_max
Subject_min
Subject_avg`

Please suggest some shell script to convert the incoming data into desired format.

Thanks
Aggarwal

Comment: Why not use a staging table and do all necessary transformations within the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in SQL, after importing the strings (as they are) into the database. However, your input string has a horrible structure, so untangling it is complicated.

Your "desired output" has only two rows; shouldn't there be four rows, since each emp_name has scores for BOTH subjects? My output has four rows. I also changed the test data a little, to make sure the right values end up in the right rows and columns; having the sequence of scores "0,1,0,0" for all combinations of emp_name/date and subject is not helpful in debugging.

I assumed the input strings may contain NULL (shown like this: '1,0,1,1,,,,," - two consecutive commas mean a NULL) for some emp_name/dates and subjects. This is why the search pattern for the SUBJ_.... values are so complicated.

Solution:

```
with
     test_data ( str ) as (
       select 'Date,Emp_name,Math_zero,Math_max,Math_min,Math_avg,'
                 || 'English_zero,English_max,English_min,English_avg' || chr(10)
                 || '20161005,abc,0,1,0,3,0,1,0,0' || chr(10)
                 || '20161005,def,1,1,0,0,0,1,5,0'
       from   dual
     ),
     line_split ( line_no, line_str ) as (
       select level, regexp_substr(str, '[^' || chr(10) || ']+', 1, level)
       from   test_data
       connect by level <= 1 + regexp_count(str, chr(10))
     ),
     cols ( idx, col ) as (
       select level, regexp_substr(line_str, '[^,]+', 1, level)
       from   ( select line_str from line_split where line_no = 1 )
       connect by level <= 1 + regexp_count(line_str, ',')
     ),
     subjects ( idx, subj ) as (
       select ceil(idx/4), substr(col, 1, instr(col, '_') - 1)
       from   cols
       where  mod(idx, 4) = 3
     )
select to_date(regexp_substr(l.line_str, '[^,]+', 1, 1), 'yyyymmdd')   as dt,
       regexp_substr(l.line_str, '[^,]+', 1, 2)                        as emp_name,
       subj                                                            as subject,
       to_number(regexp_substr(l.line_str, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, 4 * s.idx - 1, null, 1)) as subj_zero,
       to_number(regexp_substr(l.line_str, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, 4 * s.idx    , null, 1)) as subj_max,
       to_number(regexp_substr(l.line_str, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, 4 * s.idx + 1, null, 1)) as subj_min,
       to_number(regexp_substr(l.line_str, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, 4 * s.idx + 2, null, 1)) as subj_avg
from   line_split l cross join subjects s
where  l.line_no > 1
;
```

**Output** (with my test data):

```
DT         EMP_NAME SUBJECT     SUBJ_ZERO   SUBJ_MAX   SUBJ_MIN   SUBJ_AVG
---------- -------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
2016-10-05 abc      Math                0          1          0          3
2016-10-05 abc      English             0          1          0          0
2016-10-05 def      Math                1          1          0          0
2016-10-05 def      English             0          1          5          0

4 rows selected.
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This solution will work for me if I will be having input data as it is in my database.
But the challenge here is that we are getting this type of input data in csv file and we need to load this data into oracle table using unix scrip
Oracle table :
Date    ,emp_name,subject,subject_zero,subject_max,subject_min,subject_avg
20161005,abc     ,Math   ,0           ,1          ,0          ,0
20161005,def     ,English,0           ,1          ,0          ,0
Please suggest the way to preprocess the data from csv and load it into Oracle table using unix script.

Comment: My suggestion is that the strings should be exported to the database as they are, and then processed in the db with a query like the one I wrote. There is no legal requirement that you MUST split the input string in UNIX before putting the results in the db (or is there?) What you are looking to do will be much slower, for several reasons.

Comment: Thank you :)
I have loaded the raw data to an oracle table and now i will have to run the sql query that you have provided.
Can you please help how i have to update this query because in my original data i have 160 different subjects and five different columns for each subject as i have mentioned above.
sub_null, sub_zero, sub_max, sub_min, sub_avg
I will have to process the data from my raw data oracle table..
Thanks

Comment: Please provide me the solution for 160 subjects and five calculations for each subject
sub_null, sub_zero, sub_max, sub_min, sub_avg
I have to pull this input data from an oracle table.

Comment: Hi,  The number of subjects is irrelevant, it is computed automatically by my query (my query does NOT assume a fixed number, like 2, of subjects, and it doesn't need to know beforehand the names of the subjects - all of that is computed by my query directly from the data, and is already done by the query I posted). The other issue is FIVE columns for each subject, instead of FOUR. You NEVER mentioned that (even though you say "as I have mentioned above" - that is simply false, you never mentioned FIVE columns before). What is `sub_null` and how is it different from `sub_zero`?

Comment: Hello, I am sorry for the miscommunication. "As i mention" i mean the way i have mentioned four columns.

Comment: @GAggarwal -  So, what does a typical row look like? Do you also have column headers like `Math_null` and `English_null`? and instead of sequences like 0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0 (eight values for two subjects) you have ten values for two subjects? If so, the query I wrote shouldn't be difficult to adapt.

Comment: Hey, I have fixed the issues that i was facing with the script with actual number of columns and data.
Only thing is that i want to process the data from an oracle table (having actual data) 
In given query we are using data from dual. Can you please help me how can i get the data from mt oracle table and process it using the query. If i am doing like this i am getting error the column mismatch (ORA-32038: number of WITH clause column names does not match number of elements in select list)
with
     test_data ( str ) as (
       select * 
       from table_name
     ),

Comment: When you use the solution with a base table, you don't need the "test_data" subquery in the WITH clause. Rather, it should begin with `with line_split ( line_no, ......` Then instead of "test_data" the "line_split" FROM clause should refer to your actual table. If you have five columns instead of four, there are some modifications needed, but I still don't know if that's the case.

Comment: Thanks for the response! appreciated 
If we do like below, then what will be the "str" here as it is giving error for "STR" invalid identifier.

with
     line_split ( line_no, line_str ) as (
       select level, regexp_substr(str, '[^' || chr(10) || ']+', 1, level)
       from  M_KPI_RAW_COUNTS
       connect by level <= 1 + regexp_count(str, chr(10))
     ),

Thanks

Comment: It should be the name of the *column* where you saved your long input string.

Comment: I have loaded the long input string into an oracle table (KPI_TEST_DATA) with only one column input (data type CLOB) and using the sql query that you have provided me like below- with line_split ( line_no, line_str ) as ( select level, regexp_substr(KPI_TEST_DATA.INPUT, '[^' || chr(10) || ']+', 1, level) from KPI_TEST_DATA connect by level <= 1 + regexp_count(KPI_TEST_DATA.INPUT, chr(10)) ), ..... and so on returning only columns- DAY,PRODUCT_CLASS,START_GP,DEV_COUNT,KPI,KPI_NULL,KPI_ZERO, KPI_MAX,KPI_MIN, KPI_AVG 
Please suggest 
Thanks

Comment: @mathguy- Please suggest me the solution. I am stuck with this issue.  
SQL query is working fine if the long input string is of varchar2 type but if I am using CLOB data type then it is not returning any data.  
_Please help me to solve this issue._  
Thanks

Comment: please provide me the solution to deal with CLOB data type used for long input string.  

I am not getting any output using the sql provided by you. I am stuck with the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best way is to use http://www.sql-workbench.net/  if You have JAVA ( 1.6 or 1.7 ) then You can prepare wbExport script and execute it from command-line shell. This tool can work in two ways with GUI and command-line. You can also integrate it with shell :

LOG_FILE=test.log

touch ${LOG_FILE}

```
echo "`date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S` STEP020 : Gathering script settings from database (BEGIN)"                         | tee -a ${LOG_FILE}    

## DATABASE CONNECTION
CONFIG_SQL_FILE=${BASE_DIR}/deamon/sql/${DB2_CFG_SCRIPT}

truncate -s0 ${DB2_CFG_LOG}  > /dev/null

echo " WbExport -file=${BASE_DIR}/deamon_settings.csv                    " >  ${CONFIG_SQL_FILE}
echo "          -type=text                                               " >> ${CONFIG_SQL_FILE}
echo "          -encoding='UTF-8'                                        " >> ${CONFIG_SQL_FILE} 
echo "          -lineEnding='lf'                                         " >> ${CONFIG_SQL_FILE}
echo "          -header=false                                            " >> ${CONFIG_SQL_FILE}
echo "          -append=false                                            " >> ${CONFIG_SQL_FILE}
echo "          -dateFormat='yyyy-MM-dd'                                 " >> ${CONFIG_SQL_FILE}
echo "          -delimiter=';'                                           " >> ${CONFIG_SQL_FILE}
echo "          -timestampFormat='yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'                   " >> ${CONFIG_SQL_FILE}
echo " ;                                                                 " >> ${CONFIG_SQL_FILE}
echo "                                                                   " >> ${CONFIG_SQL_FILE}
echo "SELECT                                                             " >> ${CONFIG_SQL_FILE}
echo "      HOST_ID, HOST_NAME, SCRIPT_PATH, CREATE_TS, UPDATE_TS,       " >> ${CONFIG_SQL_FILE}
echo "      HOST_DESC, HOST_MONIT_FREQ,HOST_MONIT_ENABLED,               " >> ${CONFIG_SQL_FILE}
echo "      PROCESS_MONIT_FREQ,  PROCESS_MONIT_ENABLED                   " >> ${CONFIG_SQL_FILE}
echo "FROM                                                               " >> ${CONFIG_SQL_FILE}
echo "      ${DB2_USERNAME}.SOME_TABLE                                   " >> ${CONFIG_SQL_FILE}
echo "WHERE                                                              " >> ${CONFIG_SQL_FILE}
echo "      LOWER(HOST_NAME)   LIKE  LOWER('${HOST_NAME}')  AND          " >> ${CONFIG_SQL_FILE}
echo "      LOWER(SCRIPT_PATH) LIKE  LOWER('${BASE_DIR}')                " >> ${CONFIG_SQL_FILE}
echo "FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;    --limit to 1 row                       " >> ${CONFIG_SQL_FILE}
echo "                                                                   " >> ${CONFIG_SQL_FILE}
echo " COMMIT;                                                           " >> ${CONFIG_SQL_FILE}
echo "                                                                   " >> ${CONFIG_SQL_FILE} 


if [ -f ${CONFIG_SQL_FILE} ]; then
        echo "`date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S` STEP020 : Failed to store setting file: ${CONFIG_SQL_FILE}"                 | tee -a ${LOG_FILE}           
        echo "`date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S` STEP020 : Gathering script settings from database (FAILED)"                 | tee -a ${LOG_FILE}   
        exit 4;
fi 

## DATABASE CONNECTION USED HERE 
java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx256m -classpath ${WORKBENCH_PATH} \
                              -jar ${DB2_JAR} \
                              -driverjar=${DB2_DRIVER} \
                              -username=${DB2_USERNAME} \
                              -password=${DB2_PASSWORD} \
                              -url=${DB2_URL} \
                              -script=${CONFIG_SQL_FILE} \
                              -logfile=${DB2_CFG_LOG} \
                              -fetchSize=100 \
                              -nosettings   > /dev/null 2>&1                              

cat ${CONFIG_SQL_FILE} | sed "s/^/`date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S` STEP020 : WORKBENCH /"                                  | tee -a ${LOG_FILE}

if [ `cat ${DB2_CFG_LOG} | grep Error | wc -l` -gt 0 ]; then 
    echo "`date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S` STEP020 : Failed to retrieve meta data (FAILED)"                                | tee -a ${LOG_FILE}       
    exit 5      
fi   

echo "`date +%Y-%m-%d\ %H:%M:%S` STEP020 : Gathering script settings from database (END-OK)"                         | tee -a ${LOG_FILE}
```

You'll have to understand a bit more SQLWorkbench to work with that, but for sure it's the best tool available now. You'll also have to download jdbc to Your target database.